How to prove limit of argmin of function involving exponents $2(1-x)^p + x^p$?
Given
$$
f(x,p) = 2(1-x)^p + x^p,
$$
define its maximizer over the domain $x\in(0,1)$
$$
x^\star(p) = \mathop{\text{argmax}}_{0<x<1} f(x,p),
$$
and then consider:
$$
x^\text{lim} = \lim_{p \rightarrow 0^+} x^\star(p).
$$
I'm convinced by numerical experiments that $x^\text{lim}=1/3$,

but I'm at a loss to how you to prove this.
I've tried looking at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x^{p - 1} p - 2 p (1 - x)^{p - 1}
= 0$, but I can't find a closed-form for its root (to then take a limit).
How can I go about this limit?

In fact, you can get a closed form of $x$ in your last equation.

For $p<1$, by Holder inequality,
$$(2(1-x)^p+x^p)^p\leq (1-x+x)(2^{\frac{1}{1-p}}+1)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}=(2^{\frac{1}{1-p}}+1)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$$
The equality holds iff
$$\frac{1-x}{2^{\frac{1}{1-p}}}=x$$
Hence $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{3}$ as $p\rightarrow 0.$

Thanks. I got confused how you were applying the Hödler inequality and ended up deriving with your encouragement that the derivative equation indeed has a closed-form root.

$(2(1-x)^p+x^p)^p\leq (1-x+x)(2^{\frac{1}{1-p}}+1)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$.

Based on @DJWCB's hint that solution to the derivative question exists in closed form:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}     & = 0 \\
p x^{p - 1} - 2 p (1 - x)^{p - 1} & = 0 \\
x^{p-1} &= 2 (1-x)^{p-1} \\
x &= 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}} (1-x) \\
\left(1+ 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\right) x &=  2^{\frac{1}{p-1}} \\
x^\star(p) &= \frac{2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}{1+ 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}
\end{align}
Now taking the limit of $x^\star(p)$ as $p\rightarrow 0^+$,
\begin{align}
x^\text{lim} = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}{1+ 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}} = \frac{ \lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+} 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}}{\lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+} 1+ 2^{\frac{1}{p-1}}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
